# How do you add a toolbar to the bottom of an NSTableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

Check the following image, how can I add this kind of bar to my own NSTableViews? Other uses are in the network preferences app. What's the magic trick to make this work?

[image: NSTableView]
[image: Network prefs]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there is any "magic trick." This is something you will have to implement yourself.

It looks like a group of *Gradient* style `NSButtons` placed below the table view. An `NSSegmentedControl` in *Small Square* style would work too.

Comment: Great suggestion, I was looking for the same thing, and resorted to using `NSSegmentedControl` with `Small Square` style.